# Display number of post published every day

Tags: posts, count

how can I display the number of posts published daily/weekly ? I don't care about caching, i can even disable it. Obviously if there is a cached way it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since the publish date is stored, you can simply range-select count for posts, which are published in a given interval range.

```
function count_posts_per_interval($seconds) {
    global $wpdb;

    $count = (array) $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare(
        "select count(ID) from wp_posts where post_status = 'publish' and post_date between date_sub(now(), interval %d second) and now();",
        $seconds
    ));

    return (int) array_shift($count);
}
```

The SQL query can take `day`,`week` etc instead of `second`, but since WordPress ships with some useful [time constants](https://codex.wordpress.org/Easier_Expression_of_Time_Constants), let's keep it that way.

```
# Retrieve number of posts posted within last day
print_r( count_posts_per_interval( DAY_IN_SECONDS ) );

# Retrieve number of posts posted within last week
print_r( count_posts_per_interval( WEEK_IN_SECONDS ) );
```

Comment: I added the function in theme-->function.php and the SQL query in a html file with <?php ?> tag but seems not working

Comment: Could you help me ?

Comment: Sorry. PHP is not executed in .html files.

Comment: Sorry for the wasting of time :D. How could I let it work then ?

Comment: No worries Roberto, you can tell me exactly what you want (like, where you'd like to place this on the site) and I'll instruct you with the right code to plug this into your site.

Comment: Sincerly i would give it a style before, so if you'd know how to display it in html with php or something else would be nice.

Comment: To better explain: `<div class="post-counter"><php code to display the number>/<html code to display the number></div>`

Comment: Pardon me, I've been away for days. Please check this code https://pastebin.com/Wmkft75Z, it will add a shortcode to use, which you can use in the editor. There are example uses in the paste.

Comment: Sadly, not working. Tryed to add all the code in a php widget and the result of all the shortcodes is always 0 (I have published a lot of post within 10 days) and also added it in theme--->functions.php but nothing :(